# Angular Directive, Scope: True AND Add attribute to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my directive is working fine, displaying all the trending tags.  The directive looks for a trendingTag property in the $scope object.  So I have scope: true

```
app.directive('ngTrending', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: true
        , replace: true
        , scope: true
        , templateUrl: '/resources/ngViews/trending.html'

    };
});
```

Now I want to be able to configure it based on options (like read-only="true") based on attribute on the directive. And be able to conditionally change minor aspects of the template based on the attirbute such tht

```
<ng-trending></ng-trending>
```

Generates the trending tags with the actions enabled. While

```
 <ng-trending read-only="true"></ng-trending>
```

generates the tags, but has the clicks disabled.  How do I code the scope on the directive so that I still inherit the scope of the controller that is hosting the directive e.g.

```
<div ng-controller="fancy">
    <ng-trending></ng-trending>
</div>
```

as is the case now (inside of the template of the directive I reference the fancyContrllers $scope.trendingTags property).  But inside of the directive's template I want to reference the "read-only" in the $scope.

It just dawns on me that I am approaching this completely wrong, and that I probably want to pass the trending tags in as well...  I am confused - please help straighten me out!

Thanks.

Comment: If you dont want to change the scope of your directive, I think that you can check for the attributes in your `link` function (`attrs.readOnly` will give your a string value). You can use `scope.$eval(attrs.readOnly)` or `$parse` for one-way and two-way bindings.

Comment: @jpmorin's suggestion worked well for me. It's not something to make a habit of, though there are certain scenarios where it can be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal procedure is to use an isolate scope to pass in any variables you want in directive (unless you need multiple directives on the element). This will result in a more reusable and testable directive, and clearer code as the directive won't be coupled to its surroundings.

For your case, if you write an isolate scope like this

```
scope: {
    trendingTags: '=',
    readOnly: '='
    // ...
}
```

Then you can bind an expression on the outer scope to `trendingTags` on the inner scope, and the same with `readOnly` using attributes on the element.

You element would then look something like this

```
<ng-trending trending-tags="trendingTags" read-only="true"></ng-trending>
```

There is some more information on isolate scope here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Comment: If it is not defined on the attribute then `scope.readOnly` will be `undefined`. You can test for this and use a default value if you like. Alternatively you can just use `scope.readOnly` itself where you just need something 'falsy' when undefined...or `!!scope.readOnly` will forcibly convert to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness here is my working solution, including bindings for the actions.  Any critiques are welcomed.  Thank you andyrooger:

The directive:

```
app.directive('ngTrending', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , transclude: true
        , replace: true
        , scope: {
            trendingTags: '='
            , displayOnly: '='
            , inlineLabel: '='
            , filterTo: '&'
            , isFilteredTo: '&'
        }
        , templateUrl: '/resources/ngViews/trending.html'

    };
});
```

The template:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div class="btn-group-xs">
        <span ng-show="(!!inlineLabel)" style="color: #81B1D9">Tagged: </span>
        <button ng-repeat="tag in trendingTags | orderBy:'count':true | limitTo:8" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"
                style="text-wrap: normal; margin: 2px;"
                ng-click="filterTo({filterToTag: tag.tagName})" ng-class="{active: isFilteredTo({filterToTag: tag.tagName}), disabled: (!!inlineLabel)}"><span
                ng-bind-html-unsafe="tag.tagName"></span> <span class="badge" ng-show="!(!!displayOnly)">{{ tag.count }}</span
        </button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" style="width: 150px; text-wrap: normal; margin-top: 3px"
            ng-click="filterTo({filterToTag: ''})" ng-show="!(!!displayOnly)">Clear
    </button>
</div>
```

In use:

```
 <ng-trending trending-tags="tags"
                    filter-to="filterTo(filterToTag)"
                    is-filtered-to="isFilteredTo(filterToTag)"></ng-trending>
```